# How to update "select-editable" value through other html elements

Tags: javascript, html

I have a web application which has a `zoom-in`, `zoom-out` and `zoom-by` feature, which I have implemented as below :

**HTML**

```
<ul class="canvas-zoom">
    <li id="id_zoom_in"><span class="icon-Icon-ZoomIn"></span><span class="lblText">Zoom In</span></li>
    <li id="id_zoom_out"><span class="icon-Icon-ZoomOut"></span><span class="lblText">Zoom Out</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="select-editable">
            <select id="id_zoom_select" class="zoom-combo-box" >
                <option value="25">25%</option>
                <option value="50">50%</option>
                <option value="66">66%</option>
                <option value="75">75%</option>
                <option value="100">100%</option>
                <option value="Fit" selected>Fit</option>
            </select>
            <input type="text" id="id_zoom_text" value="" maxlength="4" />
        </div>

        <span class="lblText">Zoom By</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
  zoom: function (event) {
        var textElem = $('.canvas-zoom #id_zoom_text'),
            selectElem = $('.canvas-zoom #id_zoom_select');

        if (this.id == "id_zoom_in") {

            var zoom_in = parseInt(textElem.val()) + 10;
            console.log("value of zoom is : " + zoom_in );
            textElem.val(zoom_in + "%");
            selectElem.val(zoom_in);
            console.log("value of zoom by should be : " + textElem.val());
            textElem.trigger('change');
        }
        else if (this.id == "id_zoom_out") {
            var zoom_out = parseInt(textElem.val()) - 10;
            console.log("value of zoom is : " + zoom_out );
            textElem.val(zoom_out + "%");
            selectElem.val(zoom_out);
            textElem.trigger('change');
        }
        else if (this.id == "id_zoom_select") {
            var zoomValue = $(this).val();
            textElem.val(zoomValue + "%");
            textElem.trigger('change');
        }
        else if (this.id == "id_zoom_text") {
            var percent = textElem.val();
            //validate the input text
            if (/^[0-9%]+$/.test(percent) && percent.indexOf("%") !== 0) {
                var symbolCount = percent.match(/%/g) || [].length;
                //append % if only numeric is entered
                if (symbolCount == 0)
                    textElem.val(percent + "%");
                percent = parseInt(percent);
                if (percent < ZOOM_MIN)
                    percent = ZOOM_MIN;
                //else if (percent > ZOOM_MAX)
                //    percent = ZOOM_MAX
            }
            else
                percent = ZOOM_MAX;

            textElem.val(percent + "%");
            selectElem.val(percent);
            ContentEditor.setCanvasArea(percent);

        }
    }
```

I am able to select the zoom percentage from `zoom-by` like so :

[image]

However, when I hit `zoom-in` or `zoom-out`, the `zoom-by` text doesn't update, unless the zoom-in/out percentage coincides with one of the preset options in the html code `[25,50,66,75,100, "Fit"]`

[image]

I was able to add some `console.log` to verify that if the zoom-in/out percentage is not one of the presets the text in zoom-by doesn't change. Ideally I would like that if the `zoom-in` increases the zoom percentage to 72% then the `zoom-by` text should show that value instead of a blank, as shown in the screenshot.

Is there a way I can implement the functionality I want to? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ok So basically you want the zoom_in or zoom_out to use the same range provided as options?

Comment: No, I have written zoom_in/out to increase/decrease the current value by 10 on each click, so I want the updated value to be reflected in the zoom by

Comment: Makes Sense. Thanks.

Comment: I've just added the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I was only able to come up with this - I hope it's exactly what you're looking for.
To avoid errors I've ran a few if statements to ensure that the zoom values matter throughout the process. Check JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mosiaonline/hqfv068o/)

```js
$(function(){
  //  Get all Zoom Controls
  var zoomInElement = $("#id_zoom_in");
  var zoomOutElement = $("#id_zoom_out");
  var zoomByElement = $("#id_zoom_select");
  var zoomValueTextElement = $("#id_zoom_text");

  function getZoomValue(){
    return zoomValueTextElement.attr("value");
  }

  function setZoomValue(value){
    zoomValueTextElement.attr("value", value);
  }
  
  zoomByElement.on('change',
    (e)=>{
      setZoomValue(e.target.value);
    }
  );

  zoomInElement.on('click', ()=>{
    // First Get the current Value
    var tempVal = getZoomValue();
    // Esnure that before performing any calculations, the current zoomvalue is not "Fit"
    if(tempVal != "Fit")
    {
     tempVal = parseInt(tempVal);
      //Before you increase by 10,  ensure that the zoom is not at 100%
      if(tempVal <= 100)
      {
        // Then increase
        tempVal += 10;
    
        //Check if the zoom is not over 100% after incrementing by 10
        if(tempVal > 100)
        {
          // then set the zoom to Max
          tempVal = "Fit";
        }
      }
    }
    setZoomValue(tempVal.toString());
  });
  
  zoomOutElement.on('click', ()=>{
    // First Get the current Value
    var tempVal = getZoomValue();
    
    // Esnure that before performing any calculations, the current zoomvalue is not "Fit"
    if(tempVal != "Fit")
    {
     // Convert value to integer
     tempVal = parseInt(tempVal);
      
      //Before you derease,  ensure that the zoom is not less than 0%
      if(tempVal > 0)
      {
        // Then decrease by 10
        tempVal -= 10;

        //Check if the zoom is not below 0% after decreasing by 10
        if(tempVal < 0)
        {
          // then set the zoom to Max
          tempVal = 0;
        }
      }
    }else{
      tempVal = 100;
    }
    setZoomValue(tempVal);
  });

});
```

```css
.zoom-button{
  display: block;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 120px;
  border: thin solid #e1e1e1;
  margin: 10px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.zoom-button:hover{
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="canvas-zoom">
 <li id="id_zoom_in" class="zoom-button"><span class="icon-Icon-ZoomIn"></span><span class="lblText">Zoom In</span></li>
 <li id="id_zoom_out" class="zoom-button"><span class="icon-Icon-ZoomOut"></span><span class="lblText">Zoom Out</span>
 </li>
 <li>
  <div class="select-editable">
   <select id="id_zoom_select" class="zoom-combo-box" >
    <option value="25">25%</option>
    <option value="50">50%</option>
    <option value="66">66%</option>
    <option value="75">75%</option>
    <option value="100">100%</option>
    <option value="Fit" selected>Fit</option>
   </select>
  </div>
  <span class="lblText">Zoom By</span>
 </li>
  <li>Current Zoom Value: 
   <input type="text" id="id_zoom_text" value="Fit" maxlength="4" /></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thank you for your response @Mosia, but when I run the code snippet here, it doesnt seem to work as desired. Have you tried running it in snippet plugin on this page?

Comment: I updated the Snippet, Yes I made a mistake when I wanted to Label the code like CSS, HTML etc.. at the beginning. Try running again? because it works on my side

Comment: I ran the updated snippet, I start out with Zoom By as 50, click Zoom Out thrice and the Zoom By stays at 50. The current zoom value is updated to 20. Not sure why its different on my end.

Comment: well.. I am not sure why that is the case but I actually added this because it works.. Let me put it on JSFiddle, because that's where I've worked it out before putting it on snipping and then testing it again.

Comment: Check the link on the answer for JSFiddle and test it there.

Comment: let me know when you've checked the JS Fiddle, then I'll remove the answer @Sourabh because on my side it's working... google chrome | Version 79.0.3945.130

Comment: It doesnt work for me still. Maybe a problem at my end. I have Version 80.0.3987.100  of Chrome. I will try to implement this in my code and let's see if it works there. Thank you for your time and effort. Really appreciate it!

Comment: Only if I knew what errors it shows on your end. But Try it out on your code and see.

Answer (score 0):

You can zoom process with CSS & jQuery

```js
/* scale : 1 is no zoom */
function zoomElement(element, scale){
  var originZoom = parseInt($(element).css("transform").match(/scale\ +\((\d)\)/m) || 1);
  var originWidth = $(element).width / originZoom;
  var originHeight = $(element).height / originZoom;
  $(element).css({
    transform:"scale("+scale+")",
    "transform-origin":"left top",
    width: (100/scale)+"%",
    height:(originHeight/scale)+"px"
  });
}

function zoom(z){
 zoomElement($("div"),z);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="zoom(.5)">0.5</button>
<button onclick="zoom(1)">1</button>
<button onclick="zoom(2)">2</button>
<button onclick="zoom(5)">5</button>
<div style="">
Hello World. This is zoom text example
</div>
```